# How do I use transactions in Spring Data Redis Reactive?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I'm trying to use `ReactiveRedisOperations` from spring-data-redis 2.1.8 to do transactions, for example:

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to do this when browsing the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/) or the `ReactiveRedisOperations`. Is this not available in the reactive client, or how can you achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL;DR: There's no proper support for Redis Transactions using the Reactive API

The reason lies in the execution model: How Redis executes transactions and how the reactive API is supposed to work.

When using transactions, a connection enters transactional state, then commands are queued and finally executed with `EXEC`. Executing queued commands with exec makes the execution of the individual commands conditional on the `EXEC` command.

Consider the following snippet (Lettuce code):

```
RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands = …;

commands.multi().then(commands.set("key", "value")).then(commands.exec());
```

This sequence shows command invocation in a somewhat linear fashion:

- Issue `MULTI`
- Once `MULTI` completes, issue a `SET` command
- Once `SET` completes, call `EXEC`

The caveat is with `SET`: `SET` only completes after calling `EXEC`. So this means we have a forward reference to the exec command. We cannot listen to a command that is going to be executed in the future.

You could apply a workaround:

```
RedisReactiveCommands<String, String> commands = …

Mono<TransactionResult> tx = commands.multi()
        .flatMap(ignore -> {

            commands.set("key", "value").doOnNext(…).subscribe();

            return commands.exec();
        });
```

The workaround would incorporate command subscription within your code (Attention: This is an anti-pattern in reactive programming). After calling `exec()`, you get the `TransactionResult` in return.

Please also note: Although you can retrieve results via `Mono<TransactionResult>`, the actual `SET` command also emits its result (see `doOnNext(…)`).

That being said, it allows us circling back to the actual question: Because these concepts do not work well together, there's no API for transactional use in Spring Data Redis.

Comment: Couldn't the "floating subscribe" anti-pattern be solved by just using `Mono.when`?`var command = commands.set("key", "value").doOnNext(…)` then `return Mono.when(commands.exec(), command)`? And with that said I can't find `multi` as a method in Spring Boot 2.4.1, was it removed?